# How to replace certain list of values in excel

Tags: excel, function, replace

I have a huge excel list. In the list, I need to replace certain list of values with something specific.Unfortunately the data is not well-structured. Only  structured and standard value is "`en_US`", "`es_ES`", "`tr_TR`".

For example,

```
abcde-en_US-as123 --> abcde-en_GL-as123
sdfg-es_ES-aoel45 --> sdfg_en_GL-aoel45
```

I would like to change all of them with "en_GL".How can I do a function to change these in Excel?

Suppose that my value is in A1. When I write the new function in B1, (=newFunction(A1)) it should bring the text in A1 as language code is changed with en_GL.

Thanks for your help!

Kind Regards,

Comment: I found a solution. I just used substitute function. No need to rediscover America. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I just used substitute function. No need to rediscover America. :)

```
SUBSTITUTE( text, old_text, new_text, [nth_appearance] )
```